# highCharts flags - drop line from flag on series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to drop lines from the flags on highStock graph to the series but I do not know how can I do something like that.

[image: highCharts drop lines from flags]

I checked [highCharts flags](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/flag-series) and I know it has Y attribute for the data but this is not what I need, first because Y is only one for number of flags and because Y value itself is not related to the Y axis scale.

I checked also [xAxis.plotLines](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.plotLines) but those lines to xAxis or yAxis and I need those lines to stop on the series like the screen shot.

This is the code for series and flags:

```
series: [{
type: 'area',
name: seriesName,
data: seriesData,
id: 'dataseries'
},
{
    type: 'flags',
    data: chartFlags,
    stackDistance: 20,
    width: 16,
    "shape": "url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)"
}]
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HighCharts flags does not support this since Y in highCharts flags not represent the y axis value and default value for it is -30. To solve this, I create invisible series from the flags value and I put those flags on this series.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [`plotOptions.flags.onSeries`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.flags.onSeries)? This seems like it would do the trick.

> onSeries: String The id of the series that the flags should be drawn
>   on. If no id is given, the flags are drawn on the x axis. Defaults to
>   undefined. Defaults to undefined.

Sample usage:

```
series: [{
type: 'area',
name: seriesName,
data: seriesData,
id: 'dataseries'
},
{
    type: 'flags',
    data: chartFlags,
    onSeries: seriesName,
    stackDistance: 20,
    width: 16,
    "shape": "url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) to add custom shape.